# Automatic Binning in Python Pandas

Tags: python, binning

I binned the values using this code:

```
desk_occ_bins = np.arange(0,df_binned_desks['Occupancy x Building x Hour'].max() + 50, 50)
desk_occ_labels = ['-'.join(map(str,(x,y))) for x, y in zip(desk_occ_bins[:-1], desk_occ_bins[1:])]
```

Is there a way to improve this code to make Python to choose the bins automatically as well. So right now there are 50 per bin. Can this be changed so the program will take the dataframe values and count what is the best number of values in a bin?

Comment: What do you want to optimize for? It is always a trade off of signal vs noise....

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html might be a good start

Comment: Take a look at http://gnpalencia.org/optbinning

Comment: "Can this be changed so the program will take the dataframe values and count what is the best number of values in a bin?" **What does "best number of values" mean**? What logic should be used to decide that?